# Spring boot JPA - bidirectional relationsship: returns foreign key instead of the related object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, foreign-keys

I have two entities: **Customer** and **Address**.

It is a ***bidirectional relationsship*** - one address can have many customers (oneToMany) and one customer can only have one address (manyToOne).

Executing GET request for customers returns:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "contact": "5512312",
        "email": "Foo@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "street": "X",
            "postalCode": 123,
            "houseNo": "10",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    }
]
```

When a new customer, with the exact same address properties as the one exists in DB - is being added with POST request, the json response returns the foreign key related to the existing object in DB instead of the object itself:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "contact": "5512312",
        "email": "Foo@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "street": "X",
            "postalCode": 123,
            "houseNo": "10",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bar",
        "contact": "5512312",
        "email": "Bar@gmail.com",
        "address": 1 <----------- it returns the foreign key instead of the object
    }
]
```

So what I **expect** is that whenever a new customer, that has an address that *already exists* in the DB, is being added - it should return the *address object* instead of the foreign key from the json response.

Code:

**Customer.java**

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@Entity
@Table
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "customer_sequence",
            sequenceName = "customer_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "customer_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String contact;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address address;
    [...]
```

**Address.java**

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@Entity
@Table
public class Address {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "address_sequence",
            sequenceName = "address_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "address_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private int postalCode;
    private String houseNo;
    private String city;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Customer> customers;
    [...]
```

**CustomerController.java**

```java
//...
@PostMapping
    public void createCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }

[...]
```

And the ***service*** that saves the customer to the DB which also makes sure that no address is being created if already exists in database (it checks on every property to be equal from the param):

```java
//...
public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        Optional<Customer> customerWithExistingAddress = customerRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getAddress().equals(customer.getAddress()))
                .findFirst();

        customerWithExistingAddress.ifPresent(c -> customer.setAddress(c.getAddress()));

        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

[...]
```

Comment: Add more details... "first POST request is executed it will return the expected output" - what request, the controller method return type is void... What database are you using...

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this behavior because of JsonIdentityInfo, so it's a serialization problem you have not a persistence one. I'm assuming you're using a relational database (Hibernate for NoSql has Jpa like annotations but then that would make this a different problem) and that data is being persisted correctly.

See [the javadocs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html):

> In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full object and object identity, and other references to the object as reference values

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the @JsonIdentityInfo